# Dynamic filtering of categories and forecasting in R

Tags: r

Following data has different categories in the 'prod' section. Need to dynamically filter out the categories and pass them through the for loop and write a separate .csv file for all categories

```
database <- data.frame(date = c("2019-12-28","2019-12-30","2019-12-30","2020-01-13","2017-07-01","2017-07-01","2017-07-01"),
                           Units = c(1,1,1,5,6,4,3),
                           prod = c("A","A","B","C","D","D","A"))

    for (i in database$prod) {
      new_data <- database %>%
        filter(prod == i)
      ##Aggregating by month
        new_data <- new_data %>% group_by(month = floor_date(date,"month")) %>%
        summarize(sales = sum(Units)) 

        salesTS <- ts(new_data$sales, frequency = 12, start = c(2017,1))
        #More lines  of codes............
        nextYearSales <- forecast(salesTS, h=12)
        r <- data.frame(nextYearSales,i)
        write.csv(r) # Each file for all categories

    }
```

Comment: Try with `for (i in unique(database$prod))`

Comment: That helps, I am not sure how to write different files in that loop

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to using iteration using `purrr` package.

Since we are not using `for` loop, we can forgo the `filter`-ing portion. Your code:

```
new_data <- database %>%
  group_by(month = floor_date(date,"month")) %>%
  summarize(sales = sum(Units)) 

salesTS <- ts(new_data$sales, frequency = 12, start = c(2017,1))
#More lines  of codes............
nextYearSales <- forecast(salesTS, h=12)
```

In the following code, we first create a list where the elements are the different dataframes containing 4 unique `prod` values. Next, we apply the `purrr::map2` function to iterate over the dataframes (`.x`) and the names of the dataframes (`.y`):

```
nextYearSales %>% 
  split(., .$prod) %>% 
  map2(., names(.), ~write.csv(.x, paste0(.y, ".csv")))
```

---

Give it a try with the `iris` dataset. The files exported are "setosa.csv", "versicolor.csv" etc.

```
iris %>% 
  split(., .$Species) %>% 
  map2(., names(.), ~write.csv(.x, paste0(.y, ".csv")))
# $setosa
# NULL
# 
# $versicolor
# NULL
# 
# $virginica
# NULL
```

Comment: Error in split.default(., .$prod) : 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach. Note, OP original approach was to filter by unique `prod`. This turns out to be a similar operation to grouping by `prod` and would be more efficient if we went from filter to group:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)

setDT(database)

database[, date := as.Date(date)]

database[by = prod,
         j = {
           sales = .SD[, .(sum_units = sum(Units)), by = floor_date(date, "month")]$sum_units
           salesTS = ts(sales, frequency = 12, start = c(2017,1))
           #More lines  of codes............
           nextYearSales <- forecast(salesTS, h=12)
           r <- data.frame(nextYearSales,prod = .BY[[1L]])
           write.csv(r) # Each file for all categories
         }]
```

Comment: Only one category gets filtered out in the end result

Comment: You run a filter for each distinct group. One category gets filtered out in each loop pass and my understanding is that you have multiple results. That is multiple Cavs. Did you run the code in my solution?